# How to tell perl to print to a file handle instead of printing the file handle?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to wrap my head around the way Perl handles the parsing of arguments to `print`.

Why does this

```
print $fh $stufftowrite
```

write to the file handle as expected, but

```
print($fh, $stufftowrite)
```

writes *the file handle* to `STDOUT` instead?

My guess is that it has something to do with the warning in the documentation of `print`:

> Be careful not to follow the print keyword with a left parenthesis unless you want the corresponding right parenthesis to terminate the arguments to the print; put parentheses around all arguments (or interpose a + , but that doesn't look as good).

Should I just get used to the first form (which just doesn't seem right to me, coming from languages that all use parentheses around function arguments), or is there a way to tell Perl to do what I want?

So far I've tried a lot of combination of parentheses around the first, second and both parameters, without success.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### On lists

The structure `bareword (LIST1), LIST2` means "apply the function `bareword` to the arguments `LIST1`", while `bareword +(LIST1), LIST2` can, but doesn't neccessarily mean "apply `bareword` to the arguments of the combined list `LIST1, LIST2`". This is important for grouping arguments:

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = (0..2);
print ($a or $b), $c;  # print $b
print +($a or $b), $c; # print $b, $c
```

The prefix `+` can also be used to distinguish hashrefs from blocks, and functions from barewords, e.g. when subscripting an hash: `$hash{shift}` returns the `shift` element, while `$hash{+shift}` calls the function `shift` and returns the hash element of the value of `shift`.

#### Indirect syntax

In object oriented Perl, you normally call methods on an object with the arrow syntax:

```
$object->method(LIST);   # call `method` on `$object` with args `LIST`.
```

However, it is possible, but *not* recommended, to use an indirect notation that puts the verb first:

```
method $object (LIST);   # the same, but stupid.
```

Because classes are just instances of themselves (in a syntactic sense), you can also call methods on them. This is why

```
new Class (ARGS);  # bad style, but pretty
```

is the same as

```
Class->new(ARGS);  # good style, but ugly
```

However, this can sometimes confuse the parser, so indirect style is not recommended.

But it does hint on what print does:

```
print $fh ARGS
```

is the same as

```
$fh->print(ARGS)
```

Indeed, the filehandle `$fh` is treated as an object of the class [`IO::Handle`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Handle.pm).

(While this is a valid *syntactic* explanation, it is not quite true. The source of `IO::Handle` itself uses the line `print $this @_;`. The print function is just defined this way.)

Comment: Is there a way to be notified when `print $fh 'text'` were called?

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you have a typo. You have put a comma between the file handle and the argument in the second print statement. If you do that, the file handle will be seen as an argument. This seems to apply only to lexical file handles. If done with a global file handle, it will produce the fatal error

```
No comma allowed after filehandle at ...
```

So, to be clear, if you absolutely have to have parentheses for your `print`, do this:

```
print($fh $stufftowrite)
```

Although personally I prefer to not use parentheses unless I have to, as they just add clutter.

Answer (score 9):

Modern Perl book states in the [Chapter 11](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_11.html) ("What to Avoid"), section "Indirect Notation Scalar Limitations":

> Another danger of the syntax is that the parser expects a single scalar expression as the object. Printing to a filehandle stored in an aggregate variable seems obvious, but it is not:

```
# DOES NOT WORK AS WRITTEN
say $config->{output} 'Fun diagnostic message!';
```

> Perl will attempt to call say on the $config object.
>   `print`, `close`, and `say`—all builtins which operate on filehandles—operate in an indirect fashion. This was fine when filehandles were package globals, but lexical filehandles ([Filehandle References](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_03.html)) make the indirect object syntax problems obvious. To solve this, disambiguate the subexpression which produces the intended invocant:

```
say {$config->{output}} 'Fun diagnostic message!';
```

Of course, `print({$fh} $stufftowrite)` is also possible.

Answer (score 3):

It's how the syntax of `print` is defined.  It's really that simple.  There's kind of nothing to fix.  If you put a comma between the file handle and the rest of the arguments, the expression is parsed as `print LIST` rather than `print FILEHANDLE LIST`.  Yes, that looks really weird.  It *is* really weird.

The way not to get parsed as `print LIST` is to supply an expression that can legally be parsed as `print FILEHANDLE LIST`.  If what you're trying to do is get parentheses around the arguments to `print` to make it look more like an ordinary function call, you can say

```
print($fh $stufftowrite); # note the lack of comma
```

You can also say

```
(print $fh $stufftowrite);
```

if what you're trying to do is set off the `print` expression from surrounding code.  The key point is that including the comma changes the parse.